# AngularJS: tree model object using dynamic template of directive

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, recursion, tree, directive

I want to travel the tree model object.

But every sub tree has different structure and append child every 1 second.

I wrote to:

[my code : jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/altanmur/6ZFmf/57/)

HTML::

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <input type="button" ng-click="init()" value="init"/>
        {{obj}}
        <hr />
        obj::
        <example obj="obj"></example>
        <hr />
        obj1::
        <example obj="obj1"></example>
        <hr />
        obj1.id::
        {{obj1.id|json}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript::

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('example', function () {
    return {
        restrict:"E",
        trunslate: true,
        scope:{
            obj:'='
        },
        controller:function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $scope.$watch($attrs.obj, function(value) {
                var template = "<ol>"; // dynamic template 
                console.log("OBJ :: ");
                f = value;
                console.log($scope.obj);
                angular.forEach($scope.obj, function(value,field){
                    if(angular.isArray(value)){
                        template += '<li>'+field;
                        template += '    <div ng-repeat="sobj in obj.' + field + '">';
                        template += '        <example obj="sobj"></example>';
                        template += '    </div>';
                        template += '</li>'; 
                    }else{
                        template += '<li>' + field + "::" + value + "</li>";    
                    }
                });
                template += "</ol>";
                $element.replaceWith($element.html(template));
            });
        }
    };
})
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
        ifdsfds:5, 
        fdsafds:'Nfdsafdase 1',
        subobj:[{
            id: 1,
            val: 'hi'
        }]
    };
    $scope.obj1 = {
        id:5, 
        fdsafds:'Nfdsafdase 1'
    };
    $scope.init = function(){
        $scope.obj = {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Nofdsafdste 61'
        }
    };
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.ajax = function(){
        var number = Math.round(Math.random()*100);

        $scope.obj1.id = number;
        //if($scope.counter++ < 10){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $scope.ajax();
            $scope.$apply();
        }, 3000);
        //}
        console.log($scope.counter + " = " + number);
    };
    $scope.ajax();
});
```

problems:

1. model changing obj.id per second using setTimeout().Working {{obj.id}} changed. But not changing model obj passed to directive.
2. not working recursive directive.
3. i want not using template field

Comment: why u are adding watch inside controller instead of a link function ??

Answer (score 0):

You should add a watcher in link function instead of controller function and replace $attrs.watch with simple watch

replace

```
  controller:function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $scope.$watch($attrs.obj, function(value) {
```

with --

```
 link:function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $scope.$watch('obj', function(value) {
```